# Attaching a debugger sometimes causes the app to crash

Tags: android, debugging

I'm developing an Android application, and sometimes when attaching a debugger to the running app, after a while it causes it to crash. The stacktrace is below.  I should mention that I'm running the N preview in the phone.

```
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Runtime aborting...
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Aborting thread:
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 WaitingForDebuggerSend (still starting up)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0x6fc6479a00
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | sysTid=18309 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x6fcd607450
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | state=R schedstat=( 4712207454 2665438173 3474 ) utm=390 stm=80 core=5 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | stack=0x6fcd509000-0x6fcd50b000 stackSize=1021KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #00 pc 0000000000479ebc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #01 pc 0000000000479eb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #02 pc 000000000044e260  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #03 pc 000000000043c33c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+56)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #04 pc 000000000043c1b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+668)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #05 pc 000000000042fd34  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+144)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #06 pc 00000000000e4d78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1208)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #07 pc 00000000002f5f48  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState19SetWaitForJdwpTokenEm+1000)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #08 pc 00000000002f5468  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEm+124)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #09 pc 00000000002f4d20  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEm+248)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #10 pc 00000000002f9d0c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1380)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #11 pc 0000000000123ba4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+804)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #12 pc 00000000001236e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #13 pc 0000000000124674  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+944)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #14 pc 000000000010bfb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+200)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #15 pc 00000000001911ac  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art19HInstructionBuilder25IsOutermostCompilingClassEt+732)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #16 pc 000000000019091c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder16BuildNewInstanceEtj+852)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #17 pc 000000000018ab78  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+3436)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #18 pc 0000000000189640  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+1600)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #19 pc 00000000001626b8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+136)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #20 pc 00000000001c1248  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS5_NS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+3280)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #21 pc 00000000001c36e4  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+472)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #22 pc 0000000000151bb8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+284)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #23 pc 000000000030d0b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+492)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #24 pc 000000000030efa4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+656)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #25 pc 0000000000466dd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+88)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #26 pc 000000000046671c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+116)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #27 pc 000000000006863c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #28 pc 000000000001d9fc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] All threads:
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] DALVIK THREADS (58):
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Runnable (still starting up)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0x6fc6479a00
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | sysTid=18309 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x6fcd607450
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | state=R schedstat=( 4767956307 2679954840 3643 ) utm=393 stm=83 core=4 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | stack=0x6fcd509000-0x6fcd50b000 stackSize=1021KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #00 pc 0000000000479ebc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #01 pc 0000000000479eb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #02 pc 000000000044e260  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #03 pc 0000000000465ba8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+832)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #04 pc 000000000045dd90  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+476)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #05 pc 000000000045d98c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+288)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #06 pc 000000000043c16c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+592)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #07 pc 000000000042fd34  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+144)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #08 pc 00000000000e4d78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1208)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #09 pc 00000000002f5f48  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState19SetWaitForJdwpTokenEm+1000)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #10 pc 00000000002f5468  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEm+124)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #11 pc 00000000002f4d20  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEm+248)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #12 pc 00000000002f9d0c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1380)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #13 pc 0000000000123ba4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+804)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #14 pc 00000000001236e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #15 pc 0000000000124674  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+944)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #16 pc 000000000010bfb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+200)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #17 pc 00000000001911ac  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art19HInstructionBuilder25IsOutermostCompilingClassEt+732)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #18 pc 000000000019091c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder16BuildNewInstanceEtj+852)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #19 pc 000000000018ab78  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+3436)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #20 pc 0000000000189640  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+1600)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #21 pc 00000000001626b8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+136)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #22 pc 00000000001c1248  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS5_NS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+3280)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #23 pc 00000000001c36e4  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+472)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #24 pc 0000000000151bb8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+284)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #25 pc 000000000030d0b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+492)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #26 pc 000000000030efa4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+656)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #27 pc 0000000000466dd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+88)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #28 pc 000000000046671c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+116)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #29 pc 000000000006863c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #30 pc 000000000001d9fc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75942ad0 self=0x6fce095a00
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | sysTid=18304 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x6fd1e50a98
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | state=R schedstat=( 12856552776 1693023464 11377 ) utm=1167 stm=117 core=5 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | stack=0x7fe807c000-0x7fe807e000 stackSize=8MB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #00 pc 0000000000479ebc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #01 pc 0000000000479eb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #02 pc 000000000044e260  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #03 pc 0000000000465ba8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+832)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #04 pc 000000000044f1c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread21RunCheckpointFunctionEv+192)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #05 pc 0000000000548f6c  /system/lib64/libart.so (artTestSuspendFromCode+24)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #06 pc 00000000000dacd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_test_suspend+68)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #07 pc 000000000010a518  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (Java_android_view_View_applyBackgroundTint__+360)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint(View.java:18322)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:18197)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:18120)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4572)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:92)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.<init>(HorizontalScrollView.java:159)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.<init>(HorizontalScrollView.java:154)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.<init>(HorizontalScrollView.java:150)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.kushtrimchatlibrary.widgets.MyHorizontalScrollView.<init>(MyHorizontalScrollView.java:16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   - locked <0x0acf94a9> (a java.lang.Object[])
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.kushtrimchatlibrary.chat.GroupCallAdapter.getView(GroupCallAdapter.java:110)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2360)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1326)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1233)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:911)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] "Signal Catcher" prio=5 tid=3 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c050d0 self=0x6fc3b98000
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | sysTid=18310 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x6fcd506450
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | state=S schedstat=( 703021 55260 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | stack=0x6fcd40c000-0x6fcd40e000 stackSize=1005KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   kernel: do_sigtimedwait+0xec/0x1dc
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   kernel: SyS_rt_sigtimedwait+0xd8/0x134
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #00 pc 000000000006ac54  /system/lib64/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+8)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #01 pc 0000000000024cc8  /system/lib64/libc.so (sigwait+64)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #02 pc 000000000044093c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9SignalSet4WaitEv+48)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #03 pc 00000000004403f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13WaitForSignalEPNS_6ThreadERNS_9SignalSetE+232)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #04 pc 000000000043e98c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+400)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #05 pc 000000000006863c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #06 pc 000000000001d9fc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c05160 self=0x6fc6427e00
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | sysTid=18311 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x6fcd409450
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | state=S schedstat=( 2373415436 183850832 3241 ) utm=218 stm=18 core=4 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | stack=0x6fcd30f000-0x6fcd311000 stackSize=1005KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98

..etc
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Comment: Nope, still happens to me from time to time. Although it seems to happen only in one of the apps that I work on, which is wierd

Comment: I'm seeing a similar error.  Only on Android N, and I think only when attached to the debugger.  I'm downloading a bunch of files and unzipping them with OkHttp, but I'm not ready to blame the library.

Comment: Happening to me also. It only happens when I run the debugger at the start of the program, not when I attach the debugger to the process.

Comment: Same here, Android 7.1.1 on Nexus 5X. Just some of apps!

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Just started out of nowhere. I'm running 7.1.1 with the Pixel. Only does it when I start an activity. Only does it when debugging.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So I was able to fix this on my project. I read [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227513&sort=-id&colspec=ID) that it had something to do with breakpoints set on nested functions. For me to solve this issue, I had to go and view all my breakpoints (Shift + Command + F8), and remove all of the breakpoints I had set. I had a few disabled breakpoints, and I didn't bother to look and see where exactly the breakpoints where, but I removed all breakpoints (both enabled and disabled) and it fixed this problem. I don't know if this has anything to do with breakpoints on nested function. Others have said that by turning off instant run it solved the problem.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. It happened to me when I switched Active Build Variant and debug (when having existing breakpoints).